# Difference between `test[test$A == "", "A"]` and `test$A[test$A == ""]`

Tags: r, dataframe

I always thought they are the same, consider:

```
test <- data.frame(A = c(NA, ""), stringsAsFactors = F)
test[test$A == "", "A"]
## [1] NA ""
test$A[test$A == ""] 
## [1] NA ""
class(test[test$A == "", "A"])
## [1] "character"
class(test$A[test$A == ""])
## [1] "character"
```

So far so good, but when doing assignment

```
test[test$A == "", "A"] <- "Unknown" # Doesn't work    
#Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, test$A == "", "A", value = "Unknown") : missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

test$A[test$A == ""] <- "Unknown" # Works perfectly
```

It seems like `test$A[test$A == ""]` ignores `NA`s somehow while `test[test$A == "", "A"]` is unable to do so.

To better illustrate this, if I have a data set containing only NA's, `test$A[test$A == ""] <- "Unknown"` still won't return an error, just won't change anything:

```
test <- data.frame(A = NA, stringsAsFactors = F)
test$A[test$A == ""] <- "Unknown"
test
##     A
## 1 <NA>
```

From the `?"["` documentation, (if I understand it correctly) it should have worked

> When replacing (that is using indexing on the lhs of an assignment) NA
>   does not select any element to be replaced. As there is ambiguity as
>   to whether an element of the rhs should be used or not, **this is only
>   allowed if the rhs value is of length one** (so the two interpretations
>   would have the same outcome)

Comment: `test[... <-` is assigning to a data.frame. `test$A[... <- ` is assigning to a character vector. `[<- = .Primitive("[<-")` is a primitive function. I guess the assignment via dataframe function has additional checks that the assignment via vector doesnt have.

Comment: @jdharrison, I would assume that too, but their both classes are `character` rather than `data.frame` so why `test[... <-` is assigning to a data.frame?

Comment: I am saying it is a parser issue. The first code is parsed and assignment to dataframe is used. The second code is parsed and assignment to vector is used. At least thats what I suspect is happening. That is in the first code assignment is determined first then subsetting in the second subsetting to vector then assignment.

Comment: @jdharrison, but `is.vector(test[test$A == "", "A"])` returns `TRUE`

Comment: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html `$` precedes `[`. The component selection is carried out first in the second example then assignment is done to a vector. In the first example assignment is done first to a data.frame. The data.frame assignment method has extra checks hence resulting in the error.

Comment: @jdharrison, post it as answer, and I'll go thru it to understand better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what is happening is related to operator precedence http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html. `$` precedes `[` as an operator.

The component selection is carried out first in the second example then assignment is done to a vector. In the first example assignment is done first to a data.frame. The data.frame assignment method has extra checks hence resulting in the error.

Also `within an expression operators of equal precedence are evaluated from left to right except where indicated` (Note that = is not necessarily an operator.)

The binary operators `::`, `:::`, `$` and `@` require names or string constants on the right hand side, and the first two also require them on the left. So for example

```
> test[['A']][test$A == ""] <- "Unknown" 
> test
        A
1    <NA>
2 Unknown
```

gives the same results as `test$A[test$A == ""] <- "Unknown"` even thou `[[` and `[` have the same precedence.

Comment: Ha, from your example I saw the actual proof. Because `test['A'][test$A == ""] <- "Unknown"` won't work because `class(test['A'])` is `data.frame`, while `test[['A']][test$A == ""] <- "Unknown"` will work because `class(test[['A']])` is `character`. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

As the copied text at the end of your post already suggests, avoid NAs b/o ambiguity (even if it works, this seems at least difficult to understand and error-prone) for "indexing" in any case. Try to handle (exclude) NAs explicitly, e.g. by

`test[(!is.na(test$A == "")) & (test$A == ""), "A"] <- "Unknown" # Does work :-)`

Comment: There are endless ways to avoid `NA`s. My question is (as the topic suggests) is what is the difference between the two methods